# Tensorflow C++ API: How to pass input parameters to CUDA kernel

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, custom-operator

I'm quite new to CUDA/C++ programming and I'm stuck at passing the input parameters to the CUDA Kernel from the Tensorflow C++ API.

First off I register the following Op:

```
REGISTER_OP("Op")
.Attr("T: {float, int64}")
.Input("in: T")
.Input("angles: T")
.Output("out: T");
```

Afterwards I want to pass the second Input (angles) through to the CPU/GPU Kernel. Somehow the following implementation works fine for the CPU implementation but throws an error in Python when I run it on my GPU...
Python Error message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

This is how I'm trying to access the value of the Input. Note that the input for "angles" is allways a single value (float or int):

```
void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
...
const Tensor &input_angles = context->input(1);
auto angles_flat = input_angles.flat<float>();
const float N = angles_flat(0);
...
}
```

Calling the CPU/GPU Kernels as follows:

```
...
Functor<Device, T>()(
            context->eigen_device<Device>(),
            static_cast<int>(input_tensor.NumElements()),
            input_tensor.flat<T>().data(),
            output_tensor->flat<T>().data(),
            N);
...
```

As I said before, running this Op on the CPU works just how I it want to, but when I run it on the GPU I always get the abovementioned Python Error... Does someone know how to fix this? I can only guess that I'm trying to access a wrong address on the GPU with `angles_flat(0)`... So if anybody can help me out here it would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: The error you have is a host segfault/invalid address. It isn't coming from the GPU. It probably is coming from trying to dereference a GPU pointer in host code somewhere in your code, or from passing a GPU data container to an API expecting host data. There isn't a CUDA problem here that I see. I guess you will need to focus on data flow and usage within the Tensorflow host code.